# How to change the return value of a `make` command

Tags: makefile

I have a number of makefiles that build and run tests. I would like to create a script that makes each one and notes whether the tests passed or failed. Though I can determine test status within each make file, I am having trouble finding a way to communicate that status to the caller of the `make` command.

My first thought is to somehow affect the return value of the `make` command, though this does not seem possible. Can I do this? Is there some other form of communication I can use to express the test status to the bash script that will be calling `make`? Perhaps by using environment variables?

Thanks

Edit: It seems that I cannot set the return code for make, so for the time being I will have to make the tests, run them in the calling script instead of the makefile, note the results, and then manually run a `make clean`. I appreciate everyone's assistance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make will only return one of the following according to the source

```
#define MAKE_SUCCESS 0
#define MAKE_TROUBLE 1
#define MAKE_FAILURE 2
```

`MAKE_SUCCESS` and `MAKE_FAILURE` should be self-explanatory; `MAKE_TROUBLE` is only returned when running make with the `-q` option.

That's pretty much all you get from make, there doesn't seem to be any way to set the return code.

Answer (score 1):

The default behavior of `make` is to return failure and abandon any remaining targets if something failed.

```
for directory in */; do
    if ( cd "$directory" && make ); then
        echo "$0: Make in $directory succeeded" >&2
    else
        echo "$0: Make in $directory failed" >&2
    fi
done
```

Comment: The makefiles will build and run unit tests, and all are expected to at least make correctly. What I'm trying to do is communicate the status of the tests being run to the script that called make, though make should always return 0 if the tests compile. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Simply ensure each test leaves its result in a file unique to that test. Least friction will be to create *test*`.pass` if thes test passes, otherwise create *test*`.fail`. At the end of the test run gather up all the files and generate a report.

This scheme has two advantages that I can see:

- You can run the tests in parallel (You do us the `-jn` flag, don't you? (hint: it's the whole point of *make*))
- You can use the result files to record whether the test needs to be re-run (standard culling of work (hint: this is nearly the whole point of *make*))

Assuming the tests are called *test-blah* where *blah* is any string, and that you have a list of tests in `${tests}` (after all, you have just built them, so it's not an unreasonable assumption).

A sketch:

```
fail = ${@:%.pass=%.fail}

test-passes := $(addsuffix .pass,${tests})
${test-passes}: test-%.pass: test-%
      rm -f ${fail}
      touch $@
      $* || mv $@ ${fail}

.PHONY: all
all: ${test-passes}
all:
# Count the .pass files, and the .fail files
      echo '$(words $(wildcard *.pass)) passes'
      echo '$(words $(wildcard *.fail)) failures'
```

In more detail:

- `test-passes := $(addsuffix .pass,${tests})`
  If `${tests}` contains `test-1 test-2` (say), then `${test-passes}` will be `test-1.pass test-2.pass`
- `${test-passes}: test-%.pass: test-%`
  You've just gotta love static pattern rules.

  - This says that the file `test-1.pass` depends on the file `test-1`. Similarly for `test-2.pass`.
- If `test-1.pass` does not exist, or is older than the executable `test-1`, then *make* will run the recipe.

  - `rm -f ${fail}`
    `${fail}` expands to the target with *pass* replaced by *fail*, or `test-1.fail` in this case. The `-f` ensures the *rm* returns no error in the case that the file does not exist.
  - `touch $@` — create the *.pass* file
  - `$< || mv $@ ${fail}`
    Here we run the executable

    - If it returns success, our work is finished
    - If it fails, the output file is deleted, and `test-1.fail` is put in its place
    - Either way, *make* sees no error
- `.PHONY: all` — The *all* target is symbolic and is not a file
- `all: ${test-passes}`
  Before we run the recipe for *all*, we build and run all the tests

  - `echo '$(words $(wildcard *.pass)) passes'`
    Before passing the text to the shell, *make* expands `$(wildcard)` into a list of pass files, and then counts the files with `$(words)`. The shell gets the command `echo 4 passes` (say)

You run this with

```
$ make -j9 all
```

*Make* will keep 9 jobs running at once — lovely if you have 8 CPUs.